# AWS Athena create external table skipping empty row

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

> Hello,
> My following code can create this table successfully. But my csv files contain many empty rows. I want to create table without empty rows. Can I skip empty row when I create the table?

> ```
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS abc.test(  
> `a` string,  
> `b` string,   
> ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
> WITH
> SERDEPROPERTIES (   'serialization.format' = ',',   'field.delim' =
> ',' ) 
> LOCATION 's3://xxxxxxxxx' 
> TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false',"skip.header.line.count"="1");
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Athena there is no way to skip the empty rows while creating table. But once the table is created you can levarage CTAS to create another table by filtering for empty rows something like as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE column IS NOT NULL AND column <> ''
```

For more CTAS examples refer to this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html)